# Модераторская метка [product-discovery] требует перевода!

Tags: поддержка, предложение, статус-отложено, локализация, метка-модератора

У нас на мете есть модераторская метка [product-discovery](/questions/tagged/product-discovery). Проблема в том, что и она сама на английском, и её описание тоже.

[обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5): как лучше перевести термин product-discovery?

[предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5): может, переведём эту метку?

[поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0): как это сделать?

Comment: Минус означает то, что я не соглашаюсь, а не то, что мне вопрос не нравится.

Comment: Как такового процесса перевода метки же нет? Просто создается новая метка на русском, и старая метка делается синонимом к ней.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight и оно даже [может не работать](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292823/339911) как предполагалось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метка предназначена для использования сотрудниками компании, а не обычными модераторами сайта. Метка по умолчанию создаётся на всех мета-сайтах сети. На руСО (как и на многих других сайтах) количество вопросов с меткой нулевое. Вопросы появляются, когда есть новый функционал для представления и обсуждения, специфичный для конкретного сайта (например, [enSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product-discovery)) или для нескольких сайтов (тогда публикация появляется на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-discovery)).

Переводить метку и её описание просто ради того, чтобы оно было на языке сайта, мне кажется преждевременным. Для начала предлагаю дождаться появления хотя бы одного вопроса с упомянутой меткой.